# Не могу выровнять ссылки по правому краю в navbar, помогите

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Простая вроде задача, необходимо, чтобы ссылки в навигационной панели были выравнены по правому краю, а не по левому, как сейчас. Ничего не помогает.

```js
$('body').scrollspy({
  offset: 150,
  target: '#my-nav'
});

$("#my-nav ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
  var target = this.hash;
  var offSet = $('.navbar').height() + 16;

  e.preventDefault();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - offSet
  }, 500, function() {

    return window.history.pushState(null, null, target);
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 45px;
}

.about {
  background-color: #B6CBFC;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.portfolio {
  background-color: #B7DBE8;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

.contact {
  background-color: #94A2B2;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <nav id="my-nav" class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top bg-primary">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <div class="container-fluid">
    <main>
      <article class="my-page">
        <section id="about" class="about">
          About
        </section>
        <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
          My portfolio
        </section>
        <section id="contact" class="contact">
          Contact
        </section>

      </article>
    </main>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: А в каком, собственно, месте, Вы пытаетесь их выровнять? Ни одного указания в css нету, что бы они по-правому краю выравнивались.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что вы сделали, чтобы выровнять?

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, много чего делал, сюда не стал вставлять, т.к. не работало - и navbar-right, и с margin, и ml-auto, где-то встречал про float, но не знал как применить

Answer (score 0):

Используйте два списка. Для первого добавьте класс mr-auto.
Пример:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse text-right" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">&nbsp;<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Для Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6